# iOS - UITableViewCell initialization fail, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

i've a simple View that is the third level of a UINavigationController, it show an empty table from a nib, here is the code of the .m file:

```
#import "ThirdLevel.h"


@implementation ThirdLevel

@synthesize lista, categoria;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Categoria: %@", categoria);

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return NO;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //newtableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = "Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"premuto");

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

When i run it, the device crash and the debugger say that there is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS at this line:

```
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

i've the same code in the second level of the UINavigationController and it work fine, realy don't understand what's wrong.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
```

not

```
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = "Cell";
```

more over

```
 return cell;//not found on ur code
```

Comment: @Marco Faion no one is perfect in this world.practice will make us best.that's it.cool.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should `return cell` in this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //newtableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

**Updated:**

And as mentioned @AppleVijay add `@` when initializing `CellIdentifier`